# PHP - Difference of 20 between elements of an array without using nested loops

Tags: php, arrays

I am required to find a difference of 20 between elements of an array without using nested loops. If statements are fine. The difference must be checked between all elements not just the ones next to each other.
example of an array:
$array =array (5,2,25,1,2,21);
(i can choose my own array)

Comment: Maybe you should ask something, for us to answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Little note- while you won't be doing nested loops, if you do an array_diff in a loop technically you're nesting loops. The underlying logic of array_diff will require at least one loop internally. ( I don't know how many it truly does, but it has to iterate in order to even begin to compare the individual values. ) Why, specifically, are you not using nested loops?

Comment: because it's a university assignment. we recently learned about recursive programming and recursive functions so i'm guessing that would help in solving this problem. i tried but unfortunately can only solve it with nested loops.

Comment: Have you tried array_diff? This will return only the differences between the arrays without really any work... I guess I'm just confused on what you're looking to accomplish, specifically? Wouldn't array_diff($oneArray, $twoArray) return exactly what you want without any hand-written loops?